# wtforms model_form filter select field options

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mongoengine, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask-wtf with mongoengine. Currently, when I create a form using model_form it generates 'author' as a SelectField containing all users in the db as choices! Is there an easy way to customize model_form such that ReferenceField results are filtered? For example, the SelectField only contains users from the acme group as choices?

```
class User(db.Document):
     name = db.StringField()
     group = db.StringField(choices = (acme, apple))

class Task(db.Document):
     author = db.ReferenceField(User)
     description = db.StringField(max_length = 300)

wtfTask = model_form(Task, wtf.Form)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is my solution:

```
wtfTask = model_form(Task, wtf.Form, field_args = {'author': {'queryset': User.objects(group = 'acme').order_by('name')}})
```